# UIView should have multiple UITableViews as subview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Hi I have placed three button similar to UISegmentcontrol. But its not, its just image buttons. Here I need to have a class called MainView(UIView) and child views like Breakfast, Lunch and Dinners(UITableView for all child view). By default MainView should load the breakfast class if i click the dinner button it should take me to the dinner class.  I am able to work with single tableview but I dont know how to load other classes on clicking the button from the parent class.

The child views should appear for the full screen except the navigation items. Can you please provide me you support? Thanks

Comment: Why you cant use tababar controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching between multiple different views using a UISegmentedControl, similar to iCal or the AppStore application.
Follow this link: [HERE](http://redartisan.com/2010/6/27/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited)

The solution in this link is hands down the best solution I've found about the issue so far. With a little bit of adjustment it also worked fine with a tabBar at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display a new view controller on your navigation controller.

```
// .h file
- (IBAction)dinnerButtonPressed;

// .m file
- (IBAction)dinnerButtonPressed {
    DinnerViewController *controller = [[[DinnerViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

And connect your button to the `dinnerButtonPressed` action.

The method creates a new `DinnerViewController` and displays it onto your navigation controller. You can then configure the layout of the dinner view controller in it's own xib (for example, you could add a table view ...)

Comment: Thanks But this is not the one I am expecting. I have a navigation bar in mainview controler with back button on the left hand side. If I click that it will take me to the previous screen.

beneath the navigation bar. I have 3 Images as buttons for sementation. So this is also in mainscreen class. 

Now If I click the image 1 ie, breakfast it should load the breakfast.m below. similarly it should load lunch and dinner if i click img 2 and 3 respectively.

Comment: You might need to add a screenshot to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

From your comments to deanWombourne, I understand what you want to do. To accomplish that you have to modify the datasource that your current tableView is linked to, and then reload the tableView with new datasource.

But if I were you, I would go with deanWombourne recommendation and put each of those breakfast, lunch and dinner in separate views and push them into the stack, or I would go with UITabBar and put a tableView in each.